# Importing a library and using it in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, devanagari

My intention is to do [sandhi](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sandhi) on text inputted by the user.

I am trying to import this [sanskrit external sandhi rules module for node.js](https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/sandhi@2.0.0/index.min.js) into my code and use the functions.

My html is as follows:

```
<input id='inpo1' class= 'inpo' type='text'/>
<input id='inpo2' class= 'inpo' type='text'/>
<textarea id='res' readonly></textarea>
<button id='print'>
print
</button>
```

My js is as follows:

```
$("#print").click(function() {
    var inpo1 = $("#inpo1").val();
  var inpo2 = $("#inpo2").val();
    $("#res").val(sandhi(inpo1, inpo2));
});
```

However, it does not work as expected.

Comment: @LouysPatriceBessette Look like it's a local plugin, like Indian , but no idea what it do , OP should update the post about why used this and what expected

Comment: Console errors? Network errors? `$(this).val() + " ";` does not do anything useful

Comment: Also it is for NODE.js and is calling `require` which does not run in a browser

Comment: @mplungjan Sorry, that was a typo

Comment: Since it seems that this module was written to only run on Node.js, you'll probably have to use something like [browserify](http://browserify.org/) to bundle it before using it in the browser. I think there are other bundlers that can do similar things, but I've only ever needed to work with Node code in Node, so I haven't explored that enough to be help with that.